# Downloading a file from the internet with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm trying to retrieve CSV data from a website through this [link](https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Txt/Synop/Archive/synop.201708.csv.gz).

When downloaded manually you get `synop.201708.csv.gz` which is in fact a csv wrongly named .gz, it weights 2233KB

When running this code :

```
import urllib

file_date = '201708'
file_url = "https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Txt/Synop/Archive/synop.{}.csv.gz".format(file_date)
output_file_name = "{}.csv.gz".format(file_date)

print "downloading {} to {}".format(file_url, output_file_name)
urllib.urlretrieve (file_url, output_file_name)
```

I'm getting a corrupted ~361Kb file

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the content of downloaded file? Trimmed data or actually some web page with warning about something?

Comment: The csv file content is  meteo stations data

Comment: **From** output_file_name = "{}.csv.gz".format(file_date) **to** output_file_name = "{}.csv".format(file_date)

Comment: @JoaoVitorino and how will changing the name of the output change the input being received?

Comment: Both of these retrieve the exact same file correctly. The file is not corrupted and is indeed gzip compressed. There's nothing wrong with your code, it does exactly what you are asking it to do.

Comment: @pvg wow that is CRAZY, my browser (chrome) is unzipping the file without telling me and is keeping it named .gz (that is why I thought that I was getting an unzipped file)

Comment: @sliders_alpha Happens. wget or curl are usually good ways to check this stuff in case of browser weirdness.

Comment: @HonzaSedloň what do you find corrupted about the file? I get a regular looking `;` separated file.

Comment: There is nothing weird about this. If a browser gets a HTTP header telling it that the content is GZIPped, then it extracts it upon download. This is because a lot of webpages are compressed to speed-up loading. This happens a lot under the scene. But, yep, it is a kind of bug. Whose? The webserver's that sent the wrong header, or browser's that reacts wrongly to right header, or both messed up.

Comment: @Dalen well I did not knew that, that's is actually the first time that I downloaded a .gz file. even if it's 'normal' I find it poorly done, the output is a csv file, but the browser named it .csv.gz making me think that it was suposed to be an archive

Comment: @sliders_alpha : browser mixed header and extension. It shouldn't have done that. The automatic gzipping happens for transfer purposes but browser didn't recognize that it is actual file and that it should leave it as it is. Instead it unzipped it as if it is a page, and didn't change the extension because it never does. Now, either browser is stupid or programers on server side forgot to add necessarry headers like Content-Disposition to tell the browser that this is a file to be saved.

Comment: If you need uncompressed csv in Python, use gzip module to unpack the stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that the MétéoFrance site is misusing the `Content-Encoding` header. The website reports that it is serving you a gzip file (`Content-Type: application/x-gzip`) and that it is encoding it in gzip format for the transfer (`Content-Encoding: x-gzip`). It is also saying the page is an attachment, which should be saved under its normal name (`Content-Disposition: attachment`)

In a vacuum, this would make sense (to a degree; compressing an already compressed file is mostly useless): The server serves a gzip file and compresses it again for transport. Upon receipt, your browser undoes the transport compression and saves the original gzip file. Here, it decompresses the stream, but since it wasn't compressed again, it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As pvg said :

the file downloaded by `urllib.urlretrieve` is a compressed archive and not a csv file, everything is fine

I thought that I was suposed to get a csv named as .gz because when I was downloading it manually through my browser (chrome) it was then unziping it without telling me and it kept the unziped file name .gz